# How to tell babel loaded as CDN script to use ES6 modules?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, babeljs, es6-modules

I am testing a React environment without a build process by loading React and Babel scripts directly from CDN.

When I try to add ES6 modules I run into a problem: `babel` converts `import` back down to `require`, which is not working in the browser.

Since there is no babel config file how can I tell babel not to do this? In other words, how can I load React with script tags from CDN and still use ES6 modules?

HTML

```html
<head>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/react@18/umd/react.development.js" crossorigin></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@18/umd/react-dom.development.js" crossorigin></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/babel-standalone@6/babel.min.js"></script>
    
    <!-- babel for JSX and datatype to use modules --> 
    <script defer type="text/babel" data-type="module" src="main.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="main"></div>
</body>
```

MAIN.JS (works except for the `import`)

```
import { Drawing } from "./drawing"

const App = () => {
    
    return <div>
        <h1>Just a test</h1>
        <Drawing />
    </div>
}

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.querySelector('#main'))
root.render(<App />)
```

*PS I realise this setup is not optimised for production, but it is ideal for quickly sketching out ideas (no bundle process, no node modules folder with 30.000 packages).*

Answer (score 1):

Babel standalone [added support for browser-native modules in v7.10.0](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-standalone#script-tags) (including the `data-type="module"` attribute), while you're using v6. Removing the version number in the CDN or defining a specific one >= 7.10.0 fixes the transform-to-require issue.

However, you have two other issues.

The first one is trivial: ES6 native modules don't automatically resolve the file extension, so you need to do `import { Drawing } from "./drawing.js"` instead of `import { Drawing } from "./drawing"`.

Secondly though, Babel won't transform the files that you import, so that JSX would be considered invalid. This leaves you with two options.

1. Create your own import function, and manually import like this ([working example](https://codesandbox.io/s/nervous-flower-irk4k3?file=/index.html))

```js
async function imp(path, requestOrigin) {
  const { href } = new URL(path,
    requestOrigin
    ? requestOrigin.slice(0, requestOrigin.lastIndexOf("/"))
    : location.href
  ); // so the paths won't be messed up
  const res = await fetch(href);
  const text = await res.text();
  const { code } = Babel.transform(text, { presets: ["react"] });
  return await import(`data:application/javascript,${encodeURIComponent(code)}`);
}
```

Usage:

```js
const { Drawing } = await imp("./drawing.js");

// if you're in a "nested" route, e.g. "/components/Button.js", you need to provide the file
const { OtherComponent } = await imp("./hello.js", import.meta.url);
```

2. <s><sup>okay, okay, WHY though wouldn't you use a bundler?? This is how the world works and always will (for the forseeable furture, i.e.)... I mean, just install [parcel](https://parceljs.org) globally and you're like, done in two seconds with just a single command</sup></s>

Comment: Thanks, using babel 7 indeed fixes the error! But as you say JSX in modules is still ignored. The custom `imp` function is certainly cool but it defies the purpose a bit if the code becomes too different. My goal is to be able to do some quick sketches without installing the whole development environment every time. Of course I can also do that online, but this was a local attempt :)

Comment: @Kokodoko well, the best way is probably to make your own CLI tool then... shouldn't be too hard. It's kinda difficult working with Babel and modules in a browser-only environment...

Comment: And the CLI tool would run babel on the local modules before the project is run? The other quick and dirty way is to keep all the components in one big JS file (since that IS understood by Babel, which I also find a bit weird). Thanks for your insights!

Comment: @Kokodoko actually, no need to re-invent the wheel. I hate to deviate so much from your purpose/question, but as I mentioned, you could just do something like [Parcel](https://parceljs.org/recipes/react/) for React, although you'll still need the packages... (you can just use a cache system like pnpm to do prevent re-installing though.)

Comment: Yeah I know, the battle to get it working takes more time than installing parcel :) But it's SO CLOSE.... I find it quite cool that many libraries these days have ES6 versions you can load via a script tag, so that you can skip the whole `npm install` and build step. (for example, ThreeJS).

Comment: @Kokodoko yep. But CDN links existed before bundlers.